# vim substitution of register following capture group

Tags: vim

Unexpected behavior of the :s[ubstitution] function.

Given the file:

```
dog
cat
cow
```

And a populated register 'a':

```
let @a='fish'
```

Executing the following command:

```
:%s/\(cat\)/\1\=@a/g
```

Modifies the file to be:

```
dog
cat=@a
cow
```

Where I would expect the output to be:

```
dog
catfish
cow
```

Does there need to be some kind of encapsulation/delimiter of the capture group symbol or register symbol in the :s function for these to work as intended when next to each other?

Comment: It's a "register", not a "buffer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\=` must come at the start of the replacement part.

Wrong:

```
:s/cat/&\=@a                 <-- cat\=@a
```

Right:

```
:s/cat/\=submatch(0) . @a    <-- catfish
```

See `:help s/\=`.

Comment: Thanks! I found the help which I think you are referring to here: `:help :s\=` and `:help sub-replace-\=` also known as **sub-replace-special** and **sub-replace-expression** respectively

Answer (score 0):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to insert the content of `a` register.

```
:%s/cat/&<C-R>a/g
```